# Why tar command uses gzip command through 'z' option?

Tags: tar, command, gzip, options

In Linux Ubuntu about the 'tar' command for these versions:

```
tar -tzf  /path/to/filename.tar.gz # Show the content
tar -xzf  /path/to/filename.tar.gz # Extract the content
```

Observe both commands use the `z` option, and well, they work as expected.

Through `man tar`, about the `z` option, it indicates:

```
   -z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip
          Filter the archive through gzip(1).
```

**Question**

- Why `tar` command uses `gzip` command through `'z'` option?

**Extra Question**

About the `Filter the archive through gzip(1).` part.

- Why is need it `"filter"` in the two commands shown above? or What is the meaning or context of `filter`?

Comment: A broad meaning of "filter": any program that reads data from stdin, does something (or nothing) to the data and writes the result to stdout. `tar -xzf /path/to/filename.tar.gz` is equivalent to `</path/to/filename.tar.gz gzip -cd | tar -xf -` where `gzip -cd` is a filter. Similarly `tar -czf /path/to/filename.tar.gz …` is equivalent to `tar -cf - … | gzip -c >/path/to/filename.tar.gz` where `gzip -c` is a filter. It's a courtesy of `tar` it provides this `-z` option to save you some effort of creating a pipeline that requires some knowledge of `gzip` and its options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Archiving and compression are two separate things.

Most archiving programs on Windows (e.g. `zip`, `7z`, `rar`, and many more) combine the two into one program that does both archiving and compression - so people who are used to using Windows tend to think of them as being just one inseparable thing.

While many of these programs exist on unix/linux, largely for compatibility with non-unix systens, it is far more common for the compressing and archiving functionality to be done by separate programs.  Unlike MS-DOS/Windows archivers, unix-native programs understand and make use of unix file metadata like ownership and permissions, and some even handle ACLs correctly.

`tar` is an archiving program.  It allows one or more files to be stored in a .tar archive. This archive is not compressed.  It was originally used for writing a stream containing multiple files and associated metadata (filenames, ownership, perms, etc) to tape. Or to a file, as any stream of bytes can be redirected to a file or piped to another program.  `tar` is not the only archiving program around, there are many others including `cpio`, `ar`, `afio`, `pax`, and more.

`gzip` is a compression program.  It can compress any single file to a compressed version of itself. Or it can compress data from stdin and output it to stdout (i.e. it can work as a "filter"). Again, `gzip` is not the only compression/decompression program around, it is one of many.

`tar` can use `gzip` to compress a .tar archive before it is written to disk.  And to decompress a compressed archive before reading from it.

Depending on what version of `tar` you have, it may be able to use other compression programs instead of, or as well as, `gzip`.  For example, GNU tar has the following compression-related options:

> Compression options
>
> `-a`, `--auto-compress` Use archive suffix to determine the compression program.
>
> `-I`, `--use-compress-program=COMMAND` Filter  data  through COMMAND.  It must accept the `-d` option, for decompression.  The argument can contain command line options.
>
> `-j`, `--bzip2` Filter the archive through bzip2(1).
>
> `-J`, `--xz` Filter the archive through xz(1).
>
> `--lzip` Filter the archive through lzip(1).
>
> `--lzma` Filter the archive through lzma(1).
>
> `--lzop` Filter the archive through lzop(1).
>
> `--no-auto-compress` Do not use archive suffix to determine the compression program.
>
> `-z`, `--gzip`, `--gunzip`, `--ungzip` Filter the archive through gzip(1).
>
> `-Z`, `--compress`, `--uncompress` Filter the archive through compress(1).
>
> `--zstd` Filter the archive through zstd(1).

And, worth noting, the other archiving programs can also be used with compression programs - either through command-line options like `-z` or `-Z`, etc; or by piping the output of the archiver into a compression program before redirecting the compressor's output to a file (or, conversely, piping the output of a decompressing program into an archiver to list or extract its contents)

You can "mix-and-match" the archiving and compression programs as needed, allowing you to take advantage of improvements in archiving and/or compression technology.

Most archivers, including GNU tar, support this via pipes, but GNU tar also has several built-in options for some well-known programs AND a convenient `-I` option for using other compression programs that don't have their own built-in option - perhaps implementing a new compression algorithm or a new implementation of an existing algorithm.   For example, programs like `pigz`, `pixz`, `pbzip2` etc (instead of `gzip`, `xz`, `bzip2`, etc) which are parallelised versions of those compression programs which can take advantage of multi-core/multi-thread CPUs to greatly reduce the time needed to compress or decompress the data.

---

A "filter" is a generic term for a program used in a pipeline to process (and possibly modify in some way) the output of one program before either redirecting it to a file or piping it to the next program in the pipeline.

Some programs (like `tar` with `-z` etc) can set up the filtering pipeline themselves, without requiring the user to do it in the shell (e.g. `tar xfz filename.tar.gz` is basically the same as `gzip -d filename.tar.gz | tar xf -`, and `tar cfz filename.tar.gz ...` is essentially the same as `tar cf - ... | gzip > filename.tar.gz`)

Many unix programs are written so that they can be used as filters in a pipeline - e.g. `gzip` can compress either an existing file or it can compress its input stream (stdin) and send the output to stdout....and a simple program like `cat` can just pass its stdin directly to stdout or optionally number the lines (with `-n`), make end-of-line and control and other codes visible (with options like `-v`, `-E`, `-A`, `-t`).

BTW, because pipelines are so useful, it's very common for people to write their own scripts (in awk or perl or whatever) so that they are capable of taking their input from stdin and writing to stdout - i.e. it's common for people to write their own filters.

Comment: Thanks, now is clear why the file is created as `tar.gz` (two extensions as one together)